# Meaningfull charts for Motion Sensors - Accelerometer, Gyroscope and Magnetometer

Tags: android, sensors, android-sensors, tilt-sensor, sensor-fusion

I am working on Motion sensor - Accelerometer , Gyroscope and Magnetometer.I am developing  c-application which could read the data from these hardware .I am able to do this for their hardware board.
But I want to diplay these data in some meaning full form to the user.I have a graphics library which can plot graph (broken Line Graph) , draw line , circle , Square and Dot for me.I wanted to know is there any particular charts(meaning ful - circle, square, etc) which I can draw with these data.
I can show simply the X,Y and Z axis data changing rapidly while turning the Motion Sensor Board but are there any charts which I can draw and contain the data for these sensors for all the axis but can produce a meaningful graphs/charts.
like  Charts for Magnetometer : [For Magnetometer](http://www.google.co.in/imgres?hl=en&safe=active&sa=X&tbo=d&biw=1517&bih=705&tbm=isch&tbnid=5yYFxiZrPJ75FM%3a&imgrefurl=http://www.opticsinfobase.org/oe/fulltext.cfm?uri=oe-20-13-14201&docid=XDTUgQLbEgCZbM&imgurl=http://imagebank.osa.org/getImage.xqy%253Fimg%253DLmxhcmdlLG9lLTIwLTEzLTE0MjAxLWcwMDc&w=500&h=442&ei=-k7-UIvQKYPJmAWusIHYDw&zoom=1&iact=hc&vpx=256&vpy=163&dur=300&hovh=166&hovw=190&tx=120&ty=125&sig=100072393721147657172&page=2&tbnh=148&tbnw=168&start=32&ndsp=41&ved=1t:429,r:33,s:0,i:186)

I wanted to know what meaning full Charts can be draw with the Motion Sensors Values.
Rgds,
softy

Answer (score 0):

You can find a nice chart in Android SDK documentation:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_overview.html#sensors-coords

Comment: Where is the chart then?